# Jquery serialize not working with Thymeleaf form

Tags: jquery, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf in my Spring MVC 3 project.
Here is my form

```
<form id="idenForm" th:object="${identifierBean}"
th:action="@{/spring/addIndentifier}" method="get">
<table>


    <tr>
        <td>Identifier Number:</td>
        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{idNumber}" id="idNumber"
            name="idNumber" /></td>
        <td>Issue Location:</td>
        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{issueLocation}"
            id="issueLocation" name="issueLocation" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Issue Date:</td>
        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{issueDate}"
            th:class="datepicker" id="issueDate" name="issueDate" /></td>
        <td>Expiry Date:</td>
        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{expiryDate}"
            th:class="datepicker" id="expiryDate" name="expiryDate" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td>
            <button id="idenButton" name="idenButton"
                onclick="doAjaxCallIdentifier()" type="button">Add
                Identifier</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Here is my javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doAjaxCallIdentifier() {
    var idNumber = $('#idNumber').val();
    var issueLocation = $('#issueLocation').val();
    var issueDate = $('#issueDate').val();
    var expiryDate = $('#expiryDate').val();
    var formData=$("#idenForm").serialize();
    alert(formData);
    var url='/SpringUI/spring/addIndentifier';
    $("#content").load(url,data);
    }
```

When I serialize the form I get blank data in alert box.I  can't understand the problem.
Here is the html version of the form

```
<form id="idenForm" method="get" action="/SpringUI/spring/addIndentifier">
<table>


    <tr>
        <td>Identifier Number:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="idNumber" name="idNumber" value="" /></td>
        <td>Issue Location:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="issueLocation" name="issueLocation" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Issue Date:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="issueDate" name="issueDate" class="datepicker" value="" /></td>
        <td>Expiry Date:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="expiryDate" name="expiryDate" class="datepicker" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td>
            <button id="idenButton" name="idenButton" onclick="doAjaxCallIdentifier()" type="button">Add
                Identifier</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you post instead the rendered HTML?!

Comment: Added the html version.Please see the edit

Comment: Check your console for error. It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/q8hbq/